# How to auto bracket ( ) referenced math equation numbers?

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing, texstudio, preamble

For example, a math equation is labelled using \label{my_equation}

Then I refer to it later using \ref{my_equation}

However, what I get is just a number say 11, instead of what is more mainstream which is (11) i.e. the equation number with brackets around it

Do I must put brackets manually every time or is that some way to hard code this?

Comment: `\eqref` from amsmath

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Crying now, wish I knew this before 200 \ref ago

Comment: Just think you could have been saved typing `()` by typing an extra `eq` each time: a massive saving:-)

Comment: @BeachedWhale You can easily do a search and replace with regular expressions: search `\(\\(ref\{.+?\})\)` replace `\\eq\1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\eqref` from `amsmath` adds () automatically.

More generally it adds whatever punctuation has been specified to be used in the label, so consistency is maintained even if you change the style.